# Ternary operator within [ngValue]; dynamically deselecting select value

Tags: angular, ternary-operator, angular2-forms

I have a situation where I'd like to clear the value from a select input on a form (reactive) if a user changes their selection from another dropdown (this also hides the select input in question.  Ideally I would like to be able to do this inline in the template, rather than add code to the controller.  A thought I had was to try using a ternary operator on the [ngValue] that binds my options.

Code for context:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div>
    <label for="constrainingDropdown">Constraining Dropdown</label>
    <div>
        <select name="constrainingDropdown" formControlName="constrainingDropdown">
            <option disabled value="">Select an Option</option>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of constraints" [ngValue]="opt.code">{{opt.value}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="myForm.controls.constrainingDropdown.value !== 'OPT1'">
       <div> 
            <select name="constrainingDropdown" formControlName="myDropdown">
                <option disabled value="">Select an Option</option>
   RELEVANT ==> <option *ngFor="let myOpt of options" [ngValue]="{myForm.controls.constrainingDropdown.value !== 'OPT1' ? '' : myOpt.code}">{{myOpt.value}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is causing some sort of template parse errors: is a ternary operator possible to use in ngValue?  Or will I need another solution?  Again, prefer to not write code in controller for this simple logic.

Current method: subscribing to form change event

```
this.myForm.controls['constrainingDropdown'].valueChanges.subscribe (
    (opt: string) => {
        if(opt === 'OPT1') {
           this.myForm.controls.myDropdown.patchValue('');
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you try changing `[ngValue]="{myForm.controls.constrainingDropdown.value !== 'OPT1' ? '' : myOpt.code}"` to `[value]="myForm.controls.constrainingDropdown.value !== 'OPT1' ? '' : myOpt.code"`

Comment: I never seen `[ngValue]` being used in the wild, and I'm not sure why you are wrapping the value with curly braces

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: **it is indeed possible to use ternary inside template**

What I doubt is whether your template syntax is correct. The following should work for you:

Change
 `[ngValue]="{myForm.controls.constrainingDropdown.value !== 'OPT1' ? '' : myOpt.code}"`

to
 `[value]="myForm.controls.constrainingDropdown.value !== 'OPT1' ? '' : myOpt.code"`. As I said it my comment previously, you shouldn't wrap your ternary in curly brackets. I've never seen `[ngValue]` being used before, the correct syntax is `[value]`.

Comment: Your answer worked fine for me on an input and confident if should work for select as well and should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModel` to do two-way binding, then use `ngIf` to display something:

```
<form>
  <div *ngIf="id === 1">
    <select name="id" [(ngModel)]="id">
      <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.code">
        {{option.code}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="id === 2">
    <select name="id" [(ngModel)]="id">
      <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.code">
        {{option.code}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8x5kY93WqHiFC5VW0jug?p=preview).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question really - assuming you are modeling two selections (I am), ngIf doesn't eliminate the value stored for the second even if it's no longer in the DOM.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your issue. The example above could be used to model as many selections as you want. Do you have a Plunker?

Comment: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3EH0Bw84dfJXiJU18Sa8?p=preview).  Hopefully that link works.  I would like the string value of the second select to be removed upon changing the selection of the first from 2 to 1.

Comment: You could create a [custom pipe](http://plnkr.co/edit/JvzBR2UcboNZXc28dIom?p=preview) to filter the array, but it's hard to know what's the best solution for your case without knowing its real application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few weird things with the code you've posted. I'll make my best guess as to you actually meant.

First thing being first is we're going to correct an error in your template and make the logic easier to read by removing the double !, either you meant === or you meant !== the second ! at the start is confusing and may result in unexpected behavior (assume hidden when OPT1 is selected):

```
<div [hidden]="myForm.controls.constrainingDropdown.value === 'OPT1'">
```

Then we're going to update your other dropdown which has a seemingly incorrect `formControlName` based on your example and code and instead set the name to `myDropdown` we're also going to set the ternary to render options in the event OPT1 is not selected:

```
<select name="constrainingDropdown" formControlName="myDropdown">
   <option disabled value="">Select an Option</option>
   <option *ngFor="let myOpt of options" [ngValue]="myOpt.code">{{myOpt.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Finally we're going to subscribe to the first select's `.valueChanges` and drive our custom logic from there:

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = _fb.group({
    constrainingDropdown: [''],
    myDropdown: ['']
  });

this.myForm.controls['constrainingDropdown']
  .valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if(value === 'OPT1') {
      this.myForm.controls['myDropdown'].setValue('');
      this.myForm.controls['myDropdown'].disable();
    } else {
      this.myForm.controls['myDropdown'].enable();
    }
  });
}
```

An addendum - if all we desire to do is *remove* the second dropdown's value from the overall `myForm.value` a simple `disable()` on the control is all that's required as the value only includes enabled controls' values.

Here's a [Reactive Forms Implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/oxQ67OBx4mYVHsskXlOC?p=preview)

Comment: Apologies for the typos (extra !; bad formControlName) in the code, it was the end of a long day and I overlooked a couple of things.  I was hoping to be able to do this inline in the HTML, but I ended up subscribing to the valuechange as you did.  Can you explain what the ternary operator is doing here?  From my view it looks redundant.

Comment: Your ternary is redundant, and assigns `''` for all possible values if OPT1 is selected, otherwise the actual values. I take a minimal touch approach when providing answers assuming that it was there for a reason.

Comment: Assuming that it works, it wouldn't be redundant: that's exactly what I want.  The problem is that it doesn't work.  If I have OPT2 chosen for first dropdown, make a selection for second dropdown, then choose OPT1 in first dropdown, my selection for the second dropdown is not set to empty string as I would expect based on the operator.  I'll just subscribe to the valuechange as it's not much code.

Comment: `[ngValue]` doesn't change the control's selected value in and of itself, only when something is actually changed in the select. I think that's where you were experiencing a disconnect.

Comment: Yup, sounds like that was my confusion.  Was expecting [ngValue] to change the value of the formControl.

Answer (score 0):

In reactive Forms, you can add/remove controls dynamically. You can initialize form once then add/remove the form controls as per your requirement..

Binding `formControlName` can be done through ternary operator and then in typescript add/remove those controls as per condtions applied

Example:

```
                      USING REACTIVE FORMS IN ANGULAR

TEMPLATE ( HTML )

 <input [formControlName]=" condtion ? 'control1' : 'control2'" />


TYPE SCRIPT (TS)

myFormGroup:FormGroup

ngOnInit(){
this.initForm()
this.addControlsOnContionalBasis()
}

initForm() {
  this.myFormGroup= new FormGroup({
});


addControlsOnContionalBasis(){
if(condtion){
    this.myFormGroup.addControl('control1',FormControl(null,Validators.required));


}else{
    this.myFormGroup.addControl('control2',FormControl(null,Validators.required));

}
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: In reactive Forms you can add/remove controls dynamically you initialize form ounce then add/remove the form controls as per your requirement   .. binding formControlName can be done through ternary operator and then in typescript add/remove those controls as per condtions applied ....... Thanks